# Java: Regular expression / Wild cards file path to FileInputStream

Tags: java, file-io

Can i pass "configFile" as /file/es/Promo/promo*.xml  instead of /file/es/Promo/pricing.xml

if not how can i achieve this? Please guide

```
// First create a new XMLInputFactory
XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
// Setup a new eventReader
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(configFile);
XMLEventReader eventReader = inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(in);
// Read the XML document
```

Please suggest.

Comment: please rephrase your question because its unclear

Comment: How do i pass the Wild card character to pick one of the file in the folder that matches the WILD card passed.???

Answer (score 1):

It won't work the way you suggest, so you would have to implement it yourself. You could for example do something like this:

```
String directoryName = "/file/es/Promo/";
File directory = new File(directoryName);
InputStream in = null;
for (String fileName : directory.list()) {
    if (fileName.matches("promo.*\\.xml")) {
        in = new FileInputStream(directoryName + fileName);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We achieved it by writing a method to get the FILENAME using regular expression passing the WILDCARD like pric* and PATH

```
public static String getFileName(String pFilePath, String pFilePattern) throws IOException {

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(pFilePattern);
String fileName = null;
File fileDir = new File(pFilePath);
File[] listFiles = fileDir.listFiles();

if (listFiles != null) {
for (int i = 0; i < listFiles.length; i++) {
// ignore directories
if (listFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
continue;
}
Matcher fileMatcher = pattern.matcher(listFiles[i].getName());
if (fileMatcher.find()) {
fileName = listFiles[i].getCanonicalPath();
}
} // end for()
}

return fileName;
}
```

This will give us the file name and that is passed to FileInputStream as mentioned in my Query.

Hope this will help...others